# Symfony serialize same object multiple times

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, serialization

I have a classic nested entities logic with `Category` and `Section` entities, and methods to get their parents and children.

When I serialize a Section entity I also want to have the Category it is attached to and all this Category's sections.

The problem is that the serializer removes the current Section from the Category's sections collection.

Here's the output json.

```js
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Section 1",
      "thumb": null,
      "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category 1",
        "sections": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Section 2"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Section 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I'm using [JMSSerializerBundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) with a default configuration.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your category an object instead of an array?

Comment: Because it is not a collection :)

Comment: please add information which serializer you use and how it's configured. this is for sure a circular reference issue which the serializer is trying to solve for you.

Comment: Oh ok, so the section object can only have one category? In that case why does the category have an id?

Comment: JMS remove the current section to avoid circular reference & circular serialization which will kill your app. a recommended solution is to construct a new DTO object manually.